# Mongodb Node js connectivity

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am storing the data with id,title and content in mongodb using mongoose. Backend i used is Express.js and Frontend is angular. I am successfully able to save into mongodb and fetch .Now i want to delete the particular document in mongodb.

here my backend code:-

```
const express=require('express');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const app=express();
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://joeMax:oHjfiewfhi43wuh438y3napor@cluster0-33rpr.mongodb.net/mytest?retryWrites=true',{useNewUrlParser:true})
.then(()=>{
   console.log('Database is connected');
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log('Database Connection is failed',err);
})
const Post=require('./postModel/post');
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin,X-Requested-with,Content-Type,Accept");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        next();    
})

var headersOpt = {  
    "content-type": "application/json",
};
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.post("/api/posts",(req,res,next)=>{
    headers:this.headersOpt
    const post=new Post({
        title:req.body.title,
        content:req.body.content
    });
    post.save();
    console.log("The Post is",post);
    res.status(201).json({
        message:"Sucessfully post"
    })
    console.log("The Body Tag");

})


app.delete("api/posts/:id",(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('In server Delete Method');
    Post.deleteOne({_id:req.params.id})
    .then((result)=>{
          console.log(result);
    })
    res.status(200).json({message:'Deleted'});
})

 app.use("/api/posts",(req,res,next)=>{
   Post.find()
   .then((documents)=>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Sucessfully Fetched in post find method',
        post:documents
    })   })

})

module.exports=app;
```

from my service.ts angular code:-

```
addPosst(title:string,content:string){
    const post:Post={id:null,title:title,content:content};
    this.http.post<{message:string}>('http://localhost:3000/api/posts',post)
     .subscribe((postData)=>{
       console.log("The PostData",postData);
       this.posts.push(post);
    this.postsubscription.next([...this.posts]);
     })

  }

  deletePost(postId:string)
  {
    console.log('The Postid',postId);
    this.http.delete("http://localhost:3000/api/posts/" + postId)
     .subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log('Deleted ',data);}) }
```

But when i click on delete button it showing me message of app.use() from app.js instead of displaying message of app.delete() i am not able to figure out why my routing part is not working.

Comment: The issue is when i fired http.delete() from service the node js app.delete method is getting invoked instead of it is invoking app.use() .

Answer (score 0):

In the app.delete you are missing a / in the uri definition.

If the uri is not found then the app.use will work as a middleware and that's why that piece of code it's been executed. because the incoming uri did match with the uri defined in the app.use middleware.

You should rename app.use to app.get too.